# Using functions from modules in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, module

I have following dataframe:

```
            Open     High     Low   Close
Date                
2000-02-01  6841.12 7052.22 6841.12 7050.46
2000-02-02  7063.57 7172.05 7038.71 7171.95
2000-02-03  7175.87 7354.56 7134.42 7354.26
```

I want to use functions from a different module. Say I call the module `TA.py`. In this module I enter following function:

```
def pan1(val):
    return val > val.shift(1)
```

Now, I would like to apply this function for creating a new column in the dataframe:

```
import TA as TA

df['signal'] = np.where(TA.pan1(df.High),'Yes', 'No')
```

I receive the error message that module 'TA'  has no attribute 'pan1'.

How can I reconstruct things that this is working (by keeping a module soultion)? If I use the same function in the same script (without the module) it is working.

EDIT: as explained in the comments, there are other functions in `TA.py` that I can import without problem. But this function `pan1` seems to be wrong or not usable in the current set up. So, any hint what I should do different is welcome.

Comment: What happens if, instead of the `import TA as TA` you substitute that with `from TA import pan1 as TA_pan1` and then you use it like `np.where(TA_pan1(df.High),'Yes', 'No')` ?

Comment: @BorrajaX, there comes an error: cannot import name 'pan1'

Comment: That's odd, and I probably won't be of much help, but... Maybe there's another TA module? You can try this (in two different lines):

```import TA
print TA.__file__
```

And see if the path to `TA` is pointing to the `TA` that you actually want to import? **:-S** It probably won't be that, though... Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: @BorrajaX, I can import and apply other functions from the same TA module. Therefore I assume the way the function pan1 is constructed does not work within module. But what should I do different?

Comment: Wow... That's very odd... Are you sure the last character a `1` and not a lowercase `L`? Because if you're properly using other functions from the same module, then I have no idea... (as you can see, I'm just... trying to guess weird stuff here...)

Comment: yes, sure about that

Comment: There are two possible causes: (1) the python interpreter is terribly broken and (2) you did something wrong in your module. My bet is (2). FWIW the function as you wrote it here is fine, I can put it into a module and import it from another one.

Comment: it looks like (1) is the reason

Comment: I am working with ipython notebook. When I amend the TA.py file I will have to completely shutdown the current notebook and restart it in order for the new functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

I post this as a possible solution although it should be more of a comment. I had the same issue with exactly the same error messages.  The problem was banal: I forgot to save the module (after I added the "problematic" function).  So I saved the module, I imported it again and everything worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post actual answers so you gain more reps and can comment in the future. Don't post "answers" you know are comments.